# Orthogonal bases for $L^2(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, orthogonality

I would like to understand whether 
$$
\left\lbrace \sin (n\pi x) \, e^{-\sqrt{a-(n\pi)^2}x}\right\rbrace
$$
for $a>0$, is an orthogonal bases for $L^2(0,1)$.
Do you have any smart idea how to proceed, or maybe is there any useful known result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I just realized it is clear it cannot be... just by considering the inner product between two of them with different index $n$...